# Selenium and PhantomJS don't work with an input field that isn't Loaded from the Start

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I want to fill in text inside a input field on Anki. However, the input field with the ID "f0" isn't there from the beginning. Therefore, I added this

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
caps.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
caps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_PAGE_SETTINGS_PREFIX,"Y");
System.setProperty("phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.71 Safari/537.36");
WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(caps);
//...
driver.get("https://ankiuser.net/edit/");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("f0")));
driver.findElement(By.id("f0")).sendKeys("text");
```

However, I get the execption

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: {"errorMessage":"undefined is not an object (evaluating 'b.value.length')"...
Command duration or timeout: 132 milliseconds
```

for the last line of my code snippet. (`driver.find...`)

But why do I get a timeout after 132 milliseconds? The `wait` object should wait 10 seconds, right? And why does this find method throw an error, but the `wait.until` one doesn't? If the input field isn't there, why don't I get an exception from `wait.until`?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi! I don't have much experience with Selenium, but as a tip: maybe, you would want to wait for the document state to be ready (e.g. state is interactive or complete) instead of doing `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("f0")));`. This way you can ensure the availability of the DOM elements

Comment: Thanks. So I added `driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);` before the `driver.findElement()`, but this doesn't change anything.

Comment: You said, that "input field with the ID "f0" isn't there from the beginning". Maybe further investigation in how and when this element becomes available can help you resolve your issue. Sorry, but I can't say much. Best of luck :)

Comment: I used ScriptSafe in my normal Chrome Browser. When I deactivate all scripts, the field isn't loaded. That's the reason I added JS to the capabilty of the driver. Should I do more?